# How do I iterate items in a for loop and then print the for loop iteration results into textfile?

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to store the output of a for loop into a textfile but is not the desired output as they will only print the last element everytime. 
Please do take a look at the 2nd for loop (I have tried to put the output of the for loop in a text file but they always seems to save the last element into the text file)...

```
print('\nTopic id, number of documents, list of documents with probability and represented topic words: ')
dic_topic_doc = {}
# for doc in doc_clean:
for index, doc in enumerate(doc_clean):
    bow = dictionary.doc2bow(doc)
    # get topic distribution of the ldamodel
    t = ldamodel.get_document_topics(bow)
    # sort the probability value in descending order to extract the top
    # contributing topic id
    sorted_t = sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # print only the filename
    arr = []
    r = filenames[index], sorted_t
    arr += [r]
# print(filenames[index], sorted_t)
text_file = open("text_file1.txt", "w")
for item in arr:
    text_file.write("%s\n" % str(item))
    text_file.close()
    # get the top scoring item
    top_item = sorted_t.pop(0)
    # create dictionary and keep key as topic id and filename
    # and probability in tuple as value
    dic_topic_doc.setdefault(top_item[0], []).append((filenames[index], top_item[1]))
```

The output of the arr is:

```
[('001.txt', [(4, 0.71602935), (3, 0.28154704)])]
[('002.txt', [(1, 0.7049297), (3, 0.29243866)])]
[('003.txt', [(1, 0.99487615)])]
[('004.txt', [(3, 0.99692315)])]
[('005.txt', [(3, 0.9950977)])]
[('006.txt', [(3, 0.9928176)])]
[('007.txt', [(3, 0.9953267)])]
[('008.txt', [(1, 0.7267725), (3, 0.27005684)])]
[('009.txt', [(4, 0.99464)])]
[('010.txt', [(1, 0.9942703)])]
[('011.txt', [(4, 0.66636235), (3, 0.32503912)])]
[('012.txt', [(3, 0.9957714)])]
[('013.txt', [(3, 0.9956188)])]
[('014.txt', [(3, 0.9970782)])]
[('015.txt', [(0, 0.9260712), (1, 0.07222312)])]
[('016.txt', [(3, 0.9941127)])]
[('017.txt', [(3, 0.9938843)])]
[('018.txt', [(1, 0.9922442)])]
[('019.txt', [(3, 0.99532056)])]
[('020.txt', [(1, 0.9978331)])]
[('021.txt', [(0, 0.79601324), (3, 0.20101906)])]
[('022.txt', [(3, 0.9956737)])]
[('023.txt', [(3, 0.77211946), (0, 0.22313568)])]
[('024.txt', [(1, 0.70796424), (3, 0.28902704)])]
[('025.txt', [(1, 0.99687904)])]
[('026.txt', [(1, 0.9956988)])]
[('027.txt', [(1, 0.8199397), (3, 0.1765291)])]
[('028.txt', [(4, 0.80725664), (3, 0.18847291)])]
[('029.txt', [(1, 0.9965614)])]
[('030.txt', [(3, 0.57492805), (1, 0.4226808)])]
[('031.txt', [(3, 0.99596083)])]
[('032.txt', [(3, 0.9952822)])]
[('033.txt', [(2, 0.70318085), (3, 0.2922277)])]
[('034.txt', [(1, 0.89127207), (3, 0.10545795)])]
[('035.txt', [(1, 0.722026), (3, 0.27340224)])]
[('036.txt', [(1, 0.9960558)])]
[('037.txt', [(2, 0.6491061), (3, 0.348281)])]
[('038.txt', [(3, 0.9922011)])]
[('039.txt', [(1, 0.9939154)])]
[('040.txt', [(3, 0.994332)])]
[('041.txt', [(2, 0.55159), (3, 0.44460982)])]
[('042.txt', [(2, 0.70692), (3, 0.2888305)])]
[('043.txt', [(2, 0.99319774)])]
[('044.txt', [(3, 0.9966152)])]
[('045.txt', [(4, 0.8118485), (3, 0.18499091)])]
[('046.txt', [(3, 0.99555445)])]
[('047.txt', [(0, 0.69498456), (3, 0.301216)])]
[('048.txt', [(4, 0.5628694), (3, 0.4332467)])]
[('049.txt', [(0, 0.9977888)])]
[('050.txt', [(4, 0.71272886), (3, 0.28423065)])]
[('051.txt', [(0, 0.9960364)])]
[('052.txt', [(1, 0.75808185), (4, 0.23720185)])]
[('053.txt', [(4, 0.9951011)])]
[('054.txt', [(1, 0.9947669)])]
[('055.txt', [(4, 0.99493676)])]
[('056.txt', [(2, 0.8089563), (4, 0.18770455)])]
[('057.txt', [(2, 0.99461764)])]
[('058.txt', [(0, 0.99397254)])]
[('059.txt', [(0, 0.99506336)])]
[('060.txt', [(4, 0.5311487), (1, 0.46360484)])]
[('061.txt', [(4, 0.9979783)])]
[('062.txt', [(4, 0.99500084)])]
[('063.txt', [(4, 0.5147298), (1, 0.48232165)])]
[('064.txt', [(0, 0.9976079)])]
[('065.txt', [(0, 0.75504255), (4, 0.23867798)])]
[('066.txt', [(0, 0.55720884), (4, 0.43956935)])]
[('067.txt', [(4, 0.99436694)])]
[('068.txt', [(4, 0.59490424), (1, 0.40078953)])]
[('069.txt', [(0, 0.9960368)])]
[('070.txt', [(2, 0.5861434), (4, 0.40975693)])]
[('071.txt', [(3, 0.59358937), (4, 0.40286723)])]
[('072.txt', [(4, 0.8263165), (1, 0.170669)])]
[('073.txt', [(4, 0.9940411)])]
[('074.txt', [(1, 0.7025927), (4, 0.29399806)])]
[('075.txt', [(0, 0.9965689)])]
[('076.txt', [(4, 0.9947142)])]
[('077.txt', [(4, 0.9954025)])]
[('078.txt', [(0, 0.96838295), (2, 0.028607361)])]
[('079.txt', [(4, 0.9937655)])]
[('080.txt', [(4, 0.99437577)])]
[('081.txt', [(0, 0.9953118)])]
[('082.txt', [(0, 0.9963087)])]
[('083.txt', [(1, 0.60066926), (4, 0.39384273)])]
[('084.txt', [(0, 0.99413854)])]
[('085.txt', [(1, 0.9960935)])]
[('086.txt', [(0, 0.99625784)])]
[('087.txt', [(0, 0.6497531), (4, 0.34491497)])]
[('088.txt', [(1, 0.70258677), (4, 0.2940039)])]
[('089.txt', [(0, 0.99131155)])]
[('090.txt', [(1, 0.91544366), (0, 0.08105935)])]
[('091.txt', [(4, 0.731707), (0, 0.26340982)])]
[('092.txt', [(0, 0.991419)])]
[('093.txt', [(0, 0.99421775)])]
[('094.txt', [(2, 0.99614394)])]
[('095.txt', [(0, 0.73367894), (4, 0.26461697)])]
[('096.txt', [(0, 0.99521035)])]
[('097.txt', [(4, 0.9960171)])]
[('098.txt', [(4, 0.9937229)])]
[('099.txt', [(4, 0.9939455)])]
[('100.txt', [(4, 0.99591196)])]
[('101.txt', [(3, 0.9976063)])]
[('102.txt', [(1, 0.99697727)])]
[('103.txt', [(2, 0.9963148)])]
[('104.txt', [(4, 0.8498221), (3, 0.14795008)])]
[('105.txt', [(0, 0.5934393), (1, 0.4045119)])]
[('106.txt', [(3, 0.56688505), (2, 0.4309479)])]
[('107.txt', [(3, 0.89017695), (2, 0.1069556)])]
[('108.txt', [(1, 0.9921692)])]
[('109.txt', [(3, 0.6526474), (0, 0.34404448)])]
[('110.txt', [(2, 0.6523364), (1, 0.23732765), (3, 0.10890786)])]
[('111.txt', [(2, 0.9984435)])]
[('112.txt', [(1, 0.99638546)])]
[('113.txt', [(2, 0.99526036)])]
[('114.txt', [(3, 0.9949771)])]
[('115.txt', [(4, 0.8333082), (1, 0.13397394), (3, 0.031519413)])]
[('116.txt', [(2, 0.93116885), (1, 0.06670692)])]
[('117.txt', [(1, 0.99436975)])]
[('118.txt', [(1, 0.9965262)])]
[('119.txt', [(3, 0.82268876), (1, 0.17507821)])]
[('120.txt', [(1, 0.9963602)])]
[('121.txt', [(2, 0.9975567)])]
[('122.txt', [(2, 0.9975837)])]
[('123.txt', [(0, 0.67087364), (1, 0.3223502)])]
[('124.txt', [(2, 0.99769515)])]
[('125.txt', [(1, 0.99586403)])]
[('126.txt', [(2, 0.80726296), (1, 0.19040845)])]
[('127.txt', [(3, 0.76902544), (2, 0.22932427)])]
[('128.txt', [(3, 0.9977924)])]
[('129.txt', [(3, 0.99410117)])]
[('130.txt', [(3, 0.99703735)])]
[('131.txt', [(1, 0.9959712)])]
[('132.txt', [(2, 0.6769866), (4, 0.31980133)])]
[('133.txt', [(1, 0.9948419)])]
[('134.txt', [(0, 0.5198297), (1, 0.33842823), (2, 0.14010021)])]
[('135.txt', [(0, 0.44838846), (3, 0.32033986), (1, 0.23010626)])]
[('136.txt', [(1, 0.99709207)])]
[('137.txt', [(0, 0.8783441), (2, 0.0889), (1, 0.03159054)])]
[('138.txt', [(1, 0.99661326)])]
[('139.txt', [(0, 0.6388813), (1, 0.35774702)])]
[('140.txt', [(2, 0.993027)])]
[('141.txt', [(1, 0.99740076)])]
[('142.txt', [(1, 0.99737215)])]
[('143.txt', [(1, 0.9967778)])]
[('144.txt', [(4, 0.6482304), (2, 0.3464205)])]
[('145.txt', [(3, 0.991145)])]
[('146.txt', [(2, 0.99620616)])]
[('147.txt', [(2, 0.99727434)])]
[('148.txt', [(1, 0.9970219)])]
[('149.txt', [(1, 0.99663305)])]
[('150.txt', [(0, 0.6730801), (2, 0.32252583)])]
[('151.txt', [(2, 0.71864104), (3, 0.27687418)])]
[('152.txt', [(2, 0.5830273), (0, 0.41458392)])]
[('153.txt', [(3, 0.8325644), (2, 0.16258276)])]
[('154.txt', [(2, 0.6469322), (1, 0.34925482)])]
[('155.txt', [(2, 0.99509275)])]
[('156.txt', [(2, 0.9953295)])]
[('157.txt', [(2, 0.99550176)])]
[('158.txt', [(2, 0.9961249)])]
[('159.txt', [(2, 0.610686), (0, 0.38501245)])]
[('160.txt', [(2, 0.99716145)])]
[('161.txt', [(3, 0.48505446), (2, 0.36028314), (0, 0.15067576)])]
[('162.txt', [(4, 0.49675527), (2, 0.49561986)])]
[('163.txt', [(4, 0.99753934)])]
[('164.txt', [(1, 0.6566721), (2, 0.33890736)])]
[('165.txt', [(2, 0.5288824), (3, 0.46510658)])]
[('166.txt', [(1, 0.64638895), (2, 0.350259)])]
[('167.txt', [(2, 0.6616886), (3, 0.33044046)])]
[('168.txt', [(2, 0.9941413)])]
[('169.txt', [(2, 0.58227646), (0, 0.4137176)])]
[('170.txt', [(2, 0.99611557)])]
[('171.txt', [(0, 0.9897187)])]
[('172.txt', [(2, 0.9950201)])]
[('173.txt', [(4, 0.9910078)])]
[('174.txt', [(0, 0.8987627), (2, 0.09535792)])]
[('175.txt', [(2, 0.399172), (4, 0.3129197), (1, 0.2825416)])]
[('176.txt', [(2, 0.99535024)])]
[('177.txt', [(2, 0.51980865), (0, 0.4761103)])]
[('178.txt', [(2, 0.9942798)])]
[('179.txt', [(0, 0.9978292)])]
[('180.txt', [(0, 0.99799275)])]
[('181.txt', [(0, 0.9971965)])]
[('182.txt', [(0, 0.99719584)])]
[('183.txt', [(2, 0.9947798)])]
[('184.txt', [(0, 0.9946292)])]
[('185.txt', [(2, 0.99375385)])]
[('186.txt', [(0, 0.97043765), (2, 0.026055241)])]
[('187.txt', [(2, 0.6645889), (4, 0.33031783)])]
[('188.txt', [(2, 0.5876885), (1, 0.40868264)])]
[('189.txt', [(1, 0.6894244), (2, 0.30670562)])]
[('190.txt', [(0, 0.9950181)])]
[('191.txt', [(1, 0.9896501)])]
[('192.txt', [(0, 0.99681157)])]
[('193.txt', [(1, 0.6064344), (2, 0.3890222)])]
[('194.txt', [(1, 0.6191368), (2, 0.37391865)])]
[('195.txt', [(2, 0.99624527)])]
[('196.txt', [(2, 0.82650113), (3, 0.16979064)])]
[('197.txt', [(0, 0.69186723), (2, 0.30481166)])]
[('198.txt', [(2, 0.99368984)])]
[('199.txt', [(2, 0.99674624)])]
[('200.txt', [(2, 0.533913), (0, 0.46221077)])]
[('201.txt', [(0, 0.9968048)])]
[('202.txt', [(2, 0.99731094)])]
[('203.txt', [(2, 0.68663925), (4, 0.3111823)])]
[('204.txt', [(0, 0.99631995)])]
[('205.txt', [(0, 0.99645954)])]
[('206.txt', [(2, 0.9978021)])]
[('207.txt', [(2, 0.9333098), (1, 0.063321896)])]
[('208.txt', [(0, 0.9977464)])]
[('209.txt', [(4, 0.5554451), (2, 0.43833327)])]
[('210.txt', [(1, 0.9974662)])]
[('211.txt', [(1, 0.9972499)])]
[('212.txt', [(0, 0.9977275)])]
[('213.txt', [(0, 0.99759126)])]
[('214.txt', [(2, 0.99620396)])]
[('215.txt', [(0, 0.9966316)])]
[('216.txt', [(0, 0.99804056)])]
[('217.txt', [(0, 0.65975994), (1, 0.33773333)])]
[('218.txt', [(4, 0.99706537)])]
[('219.txt', [(0, 0.99597585)])]
[('220.txt', [(0, 0.9973574)])]
[('221.txt', [(2, 0.9961178)])]
[('222.txt', [(0, 0.7885542), (1, 0.20995435)])]
[('223.txt', [(4, 0.94501954), (0, 0.052957233)])]
[('224.txt', [(0, 0.99597615)])]
[('225.txt', [(0, 0.99772716)])]
[('226.txt', [(1, 0.9972503)])]
[('227.txt', [(1, 0.9962298)])]
[('228.txt', [(0, 0.99788153)])]
[('229.txt', [(0, 0.99829)])]
[('230.txt', [(0, 0.9957878)])]
[('231.txt', [(2, 0.9967612)])]
[('232.txt', [(0, 0.9935971)])]
[('233.txt', [(4, 0.9954175)])]
[('234.txt', [(0, 0.99781704)])]
[('235.txt', [(0, 0.90009326), (4, 0.09837005)])]
[('236.txt', [(0, 0.9963427)])]
[('237.txt', [(0, 0.99463385)])]
[('238.txt', [(0, 0.7446245), (1, 0.24992703)])]
[('239.txt', [(3, 0.58633035), (0, 0.2825646), (1, 0.1281509)])]
[('240.txt', [(0, 0.99782217)])]
[('241.txt', [(1, 0.8480159), (0, 0.14756873)])]
[('242.txt', [(3, 0.9947073)])]
[('243.txt', [(2, 0.90908307), (0, 0.08884188)])]
[('244.txt', [(4, 0.9128273), (0, 0.085246615)])]
[('245.txt', [(3, 0.68367517), (2, 0.22646488), (4, 0.08881564)])]
[('246.txt', [(0, 0.9964561)])]
[('247.txt', [(0, 0.53860736), (1, 0.4575816)])]
[('248.txt', [(1, 0.99430263)])]
[('249.txt', [(2, 0.983931), (3, 0.013103891)])]
[('250.txt', [(1, 0.9961023)])]
```

Comment: open("text_file1.txt", "a")

Comment: However I guess just wait for someone to post an answer since your code isn't good practice and you should rather use `with open()`.

Comment: @SliverSlash append in the text file does not work

Comment: I have 250 lines and I want it to print them into the textfile but they always print the last element... :(( @SilverSlash

Answer (score 1):

Context handlers will automatically close out its resources after it leaves scope.  `open()` has a context handler and can be used like this:

```
with open('text_file1.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for item in arr:
        f_out.write("%s\n" % str(item))
```

In your code, you call `text_file.close()` which will close the file handler after only writing the first entry.  How you don't error out after the first `write()` statement is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the whole array in a single operation, so you do not override you file after writing each element. You can use the `with open()` method as @SilverSlash commented or the `numpy.savetxt` method which also works for lists of integers or floats.

```
import numpy    
numpy.savetxt('arr.out', arr, delimiter=',')
```

**Edit**

On your second loop remove the lines that handle the writing part and add `numpy.savetxt('arr.out', arr, delimiter=',')` at the end of the script. Remember to `import numpy` add the beginning of the script.

```
for item in arr:
    # get the top scoring item
    top_item = sorted_t.pop(0)
    # create dictionary and keep key as topic id and filename
    # and probability in tuple as value
    dic_topic_doc.setdefault(top_item[0], []).append((filenames[index], top_item[1])
numpy.savetxt('arr.out', arr, delimiter=',')
```

**Edit 2**

Looks like you list `arr` is a list of tuples containing nested lists. So `numpy.savetxt` will not work. Instead use

```
for item in arr:
        # get the top scoring item
        top_item = sorted_t.pop(0)
        # create dictionary and keep key as topic id and filename
        # and probability in tuple as value
        dic_topic_doc.setdefault(top_item[0], []).append((filenames[index], top_item[1])

with open('arr.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in arr:
        f.write("%s\n" % str(item))
```

Comment: Could you show me how do I add ur recommended codes into the for loop in my codes? @b-fg

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/topicmodel_practical/topicmodel.py", line 112, in <module>
    numpy.savetxt('arr.out', arr, delimiter=',')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1330, in savetxt
    X = np.asarray(X)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: there is a traceback error after i have tried the codes.. @b-fg

Comment: Can you show how does `arr` look like? If it's a list of integers or floats should be okay.

Comment: the array is in the codes provided @b-fg please take a look again thanks!

Comment: I mean do a `print(arr)` and show me the output of this.

Comment: I have added the output of the arr please take a look thanks @b-fg

Comment: I figured you `arr` is a list of strings. See my edit 2 on how to save this as a .txt file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182436/discussion-between-school-and-b-fg).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current code without importing extra libraries:

```
print('\nTopic id, number of documents, list of documents with probability and represented topic words: ')
dic_topic_doc = {}
# for doc in doc_clean:
for index, doc in enumerate(doc_clean):
    bow = dictionary.doc2bow(doc)
    # get topic distribution of the ldamodel
    t = ldamodel.get_document_topics(bow)
    # sort the probability value in descending order to extract the top
    # contributing topic id
    sorted_t = sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # print only the filename
    arr = []
    r = filenames[index], sorted_t
    arr += [r]
# print(filenames[index], sorted_t)
text_file = open("text_file1.txt", "a") # Just changing the open mode from w(rite) to a(ppend) does the trick
for item in arr:
    text_file.write("%s\n" % str(item))
    text_file.close()
    # get the top scoring item
    top_item = sorted_t.pop(0)
    # create dictionary and keep key as topic id and filename
    # and probability in tuple as value
    dic_topic_doc.setdefault(top_item[0], []).append((filenames[index], top_item[1]))
```

I also suggest you to read the relevant part of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: this does not work as the for loop only save the last element of the array into the text file if I do append text file then whenever I run it will just append the last element of the array... @Pitto

Comment: The problem now is that my array has 250 lines which means there are 249 indexes but they always loop index 249 and not indexes 0-248... @Pitto

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddict

dic_topic_doc = ddict(list)

text_file = open("text_file1.txt", "w")
with open('text_file1.txt', 'a') as f:
    for item in arr:
        f.write(f"{item}\n")
        top_item = sorted_t.pop(0)
        dic_topic_doc.append((filenames[index], top_item[1]))
```

Try this.

Comment: I encountered a trace back error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/topicmodel_practical/topicmodel.py", line 106, in <module>
    dic_topic_doc = ddict([])
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None @SliverSlash